# SED INSERT block of code BEFORE matched block

Tags: sed, insert, append, match, codeblocks

I have a text file I want to edit during a script excecution.
I want to pass from the text on left to the text on right using `sed` insert:

INSERT BEFORE:
from:

```
[...]
[ placeholder ]
Categ         #n
ItemName      1
[...]
[ placeholder ]
Categ         #n
ItemName      2
[...]
```

to:

```
[...]
[ placeholder ]
Categ         #n
ItemName      1
[...]
**new_line1**        <<<--- INSERT BEFORE
**new_line2**        |||
**new_line3**        |||
[ placeholder ]      <<<--- 3-lines match
Categ         #n     |||
ItemName      2      |||
[...]
```

I have tried to adapt `sed append` lines to `sed insert`.
The appending works, the insert does not.
The match to append was 2 lines one after the other.
In the insert, the match it is 3 lines and I tried to match the first and the last, as I don't know how to match the entire 3-lines block.

APPEND AFTER:

```
sed -e '/^\[ placeholder \]\/ItemName      2/a \\nnew_line1\nnew_line2\nnew_line3' input.txt
```

and it works from:

```
[...]
[ placeholder ]
ItemName      1
[...]
[ placeholder ]
ItemName      2
[...]
```

to:

```
[...]
[ placeholder ]
ItemName      1
[...]
[ placeholder ]     <<<--- 2-lines match
ItemName      2     |||
**new_line1**       <<<--- APPENDED AFTER
**new_line2**       |||
**new_line3**       |||
[...]
```

I have tried to use the syntax examples in this post, but with no success.
[The sed - Stream Editor](https://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/linux_tool_guides/the_sed_faq/sedfaq4_013.html)

Comment: I don't see how the `sed` command you tried could output what you show with the input you show. As it is, it should not change anything to the input.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet. I am sorry I cannot post the real code as it is confidential. `sed append` works fine but if you see any error, possibly it is due to different keywords I am using to translate the code. I am a beginner at bash. :)

Comment: Your pattern `\[ placeholder \]\/ItemName      2` matches the literal string `[ placeholder ]/ItemName      2` at the beginning of a line. As you don"t have anything like this in your input it doesn't match any line and `sed` shall print all lines unmodified. It is always much better to test your examples before posting them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your input does not contain `NUL` bytes you could try the following with GNU `sed`:

```
$ from='\[ placeholder \]\nCateg         #n\nItemName      2\n'
$ to='**new_line1**\n**new_line2**\n**new_line3**\n'
$ sed -Ez "s/(^|\n)($from)/\1$to\2/" input.txt
[...]
[ placeholder ]
Categ         #n
ItemName      1
[...]
**new_line1**
**new_line2**
**new_line3**
[ placeholder ]
Categ         #n
ItemName      2
[...]
```

With the `-z` option the input is treated as a set of lines, each terminated by a zero byte (the ASCII `NUL` character) instead of a newline. If the input does not contain `NUL` bytes this allows to process the entire file at once. Of course you must properly escape special characters in `from` and `to`.

Comment: your solution works perfectly with my example and with my real code! Thank you very much! It is also very straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

The problem becomes much simpler if the file is read backwards.

A `sed` solution is possible but `awk` is very straightforward:

```
tac input.txt |
awk '
    # copy every input line to output
    { print }

    # look for desired itemname line
    #   if found, change state and
    #   skip remaining tests (which can't match)
    $1=="ItemName" && $2==2 { s = 1; next }

    # if we get here, look for placeholder line
    #   if found, append new lines and reset state
    s && /\[ placeholder \]/ {
        print "new3"
        print "new2"
        print "new1"
        s = 0
    }
' | tac > output.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Your awk solution is very clear and easy to use.
I have tried it with my real code and it also works perfectly!
This text editing is part of a larger editing in sed. As I can only vote I solution, I will vote the sed one, but yours is perfectly working! Next time I will try awk to edit text! :D

Answer (score 0):

A loop probably makes sense to accumulate the block into the pattern space:

```
sed '/placeholder/{:l /ItemName/!{N;bl};/ItemName.*2/s/^/new1\nnew2\nnew3\n/}' file
```

Note that if `ItemName` is always two lines after `placeholder` then this simpler method also works:

```
sed '/placeholder/{N;N;/ItemName.*2/s/^/new1\nnew2\nnew3\n/}' file
```

There is also this complicated method of accumulating in the hold space rather than the pattern space:

```
sed '/placeholder/,/ItemName/{/placeholder/h;//!H;/ItemName/!d;//g;/ItemName.*2/s/^/new1\nnew2\nnew3\n/}' file
```

All methods produce this output:

```
[...]
[ placeholder ]
Categ         #n
ItemName      1
[...]
new1
new2
new3
[ placeholder ]
Categ         #n
ItemName      2
[...]
```

The simpler method is simply using `N` to append more lines into the pattern space before it's printed.

The loop adds a label `:l` and `b` branches to that label until `ItemName`.

The hold space method uses `h` and `H` to hold, `d` to delete and not print, `g` to get.  As well as `//` as shorthand to repeat same match.

I have been lazy with the matches and the lines inserted to make this all more readable.  `ItemName.*2` is especially lazy.  Probably should be something like `ItemName\s\+2\b`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried the 3 of them. They work perfectly with my example but not with the real code. The first solution `sed '/placeholder/{:l /ItemName/!{N;bl};/ItemName.*2/s/^/new1\nnew2\nnew3\n/}' file ` is placing the new text before the first occurrence and not the correct item (which is the second but not always).

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed and bash):

```
match=''\[ placeholder \]\nCateg         #n\nItemName      2'
insert='**new_line1**\n**new_line2**\n**new_line3**'
sed '1N;N;/^'"${match}"'$/!{P;D};i\'"${insert}" file
```

Open a three line window until a match occurs, then insert the required string and thereafter the two line window will continue until the end of file.